# Selenium-2 Webdriver browser support

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question about selenium2 (webdriver).

As selenium-2 supports following 4 types of web drivers..

1-IE

2-firefox

3-chrome

4-htmlunit

Is there any way to use any other webdriver apart from these; like Safari, Opera etc?

Answer (score 0):

In C# (I think in Java too at least), there is the RemoteWebDriver which is meant to control a WebDriver on a remote machine (although it can be done locally).

RemoteWebDriver can be given a DesiredCapability that has more options. So for example:

```
RemoteWebDriver operaDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Opera());
```